# Root canal therapy for diabetes patient?

Tags: dentistry, treatment, swelling, type-2-diabetes, root-canal

If someone has the symptoms of the damaged nerve and should undergo a root canal therapy: Is there any risk for a diabetes patient to undergo this procedure?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any risk for a diabetes patient to undergo this procedure?

Yes, root canals carry some risks for everyone, and the degree of risk depends on your health status.  Surgical risks for diabetics are generally related to how well their blood sugar is controlled and their other comorbidities.  [This is a simple MedLine article on surgery for diabetics.](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/patientinstructions/000702.htm) In general, for a dental procedure, the major potential complications that are directly related to diabetes include infection and slow healing, but others are possible.

There are several risk stratification assessments that are used to determine the level of risk someone has going into different types of procedures.  So it is impossible for anyone online to counsel you on your own risks and benefits.

You should go ASAP for evaluation of what it is.  It could be a cavity that may or may not require a root canal, or it could be an abscess developing.  Consider going to the ER if you can't get into the dentist right away - especially if you develop a fever or anything like that.